# Massaging JSON Data with underscore.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, underscore.js

I have stored the data in the following manner

```
[
  {
    "metadata": {
      "subtitle": "kit",
      "id": "0063400000yCqRfAAK",
      "title": "#9864478"
    },
    "entityTitle": "Opportunities"
  },
  {
    "metadata": {
      "subtitle": "Acceleration",
      "id": "0063400000yCqRfAAK",
      "title": "#9882278"
    },
    "entityTitle": "Reports"
  }
]
```

**I need to transform this into  :**

```
[
  {
    "entityTitle": "Opportunities",
    "searchResults": [
      {
        "subtitle": "kit",
        "id": "0063400000yCqRfAAK",
        "title": "#9864478"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "entityTitle": "Reports",
    "searchResults": [
      {
        "subtitle": "Acceleration",
        "id": "0063400000yCqRfAAK",
        "title": "#9882278"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I have used [_.groupBy](https://underscorejs.org/#groupBy) , like this

```
_.groupBy(recentData, function(data) {
            return data.entityTitle;
});
```

and I got :

```
{
  "Opportunities": [
    {
      "metadata": {
        "subtitle": "kit",
        "id": "0063400000yCqRfAAK",
        "title": "#9864478"
      },
      "entityTitle": "Opportunities"
    }
  ],
  "Reports": [
    {
      "metadata": {
        "subtitle": "Acceleration",
        "id": "0063400000yCqRfAAK",
        "title": "#9882278"
      },
      "entityTitle": "Reports"
    }
  ]
}
```

I need to store the recently searched data into an array, so I am storing the data like this.
Can anyone help please me get the data into proper format?

Comment: when you say you need to store the recently searched data, what happens next? so you get the data in the structure you want, what is returned from the second search and how do you want it to look then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a chain and map the groups created by _groupBy. The search results within each group also need mapping to remove the `metadata` property

```js
let res =
_.chain(data)
  .groupBy('entityTitle')
  .map(function(results, title) {
    return {entityTitle: title, searchResults: _.map(results, 'metadata') };
  })
  .value();


console.log(res)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100%!important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.9.1/underscore-min.js">
</script>

<script>
  data = [{
      "metadata": {
        "subtitle": "kit",
        "id": "0063400000yCqRfAAK",
        "title": "#9864478"
      },
      "entityTitle": "Opportunities"
    },
    {
      "metadata": {
        "subtitle": "foo",
        "id": "foo",
        "title": "#foo"
      },
      "entityTitle": "Opportunities"
    },
    {
      "metadata": {
        "subtitle": "Acceleration",
        "id": "0063400000yCqRfAAK",
        "title": "#9882278"
      },
      "entityTitle": "Reports"
    }
  ]
</script>
```

Comment: Amazing! Thanks. Can you please explain why we have to use _.chain?

Comment: don't *"have to"* but to do it without you would need one variable containing the group results and another to hold the final mapped results. Using chain passes the result of each method to the next

Comment: So would be like `let groups = _.groupBy(data,'entityTitle');  let results = _.map(groups....`

Comment: the docs says _.map(list,iteratee), so it should take function as second argument, right? how does _.map(results, 'metadata') works?

Comment: Good question. I don't use underscore much...prefer lodash which has much higher adoption rate. It allows passing keys as strings so i did that and it worked. Looking for documentaion in underscore docs and don't see it either

Answer (score 2):

Just a simple mapping will suffice:

```js
const data = [
  {
    "metadata": {
      "subtitle": "kit",
      "id": "0063400000yCqRfAAK",
      "title": "#9864478"
    },
    "entityTitle": "Opportunities"
  },
  {
    "metadata": {
      "subtitle": "Acceleration",
      "id": "0063400000yCqRfAAK",
      "title": "#9882278"
    },
    "entityTitle": "Reports"
  }
];
const transformation = data.map( item => ({
  "entityTitle": item.entityTitle,
  "searchResults": [
    item.metadata
  ]
}));
console.log( transformation );
```

But I would advice against storing the search results this way.
I would store the current search results in a seperate array and just have the indexes of the entity inside the entities array, so that there's a clear seperation between the searches and the entities, since the entity should not care about if it's being searched or not.

In case there's multiple entities of the same name, we can replace the mapping by a reduction:

```js
const data = [
  {
    "metadata": {
      "subtitle": "kit",
      "id": "0063400000yCqRfAAK",
      "title": "#9864478"
    },
    "entityTitle": "Opportunities"
  },
  {
    "metadata": {
      "subtitle": "Acceleration",
      "id": "0063400000yCqRfAAK",
      "title": "#9882278"
    },
    "entityTitle": "Reports"
  },
  {
    "metadata": {
      "subtitle": "kat",
      "id": "0045100000yCqRfAAK",
      "title": "#98640100"
    },
    "entityTitle": "Opportunities"
  }
];
const transformation = Object.values(
  data.reduce(( groups, item ) => {
    const entityTitle = item.entityTitle;
    if ( !groups[ entityTitle ] ) groups[ entityTitle ] = { entityTitle, "searchResults": [] };
    groups[ entityTitle ].searchResults.push( item.metadata );
    return groups;
  }, {} )
);
console.log( transformation );
```

Comment: Only works because you don't have multiples in each group. Adding another `Opportunities` will break the grouping

Comment: Yes, but metadata is an object, so there won't be multiple metadata keys on the source. And the OP makes no reference of that there might be more than one entity with the same title. If so, the mapping should become a reduction into a groups hash and then a mapping back to an array. I'll add that too then.

Comment: Thank you @charlietfl. Sorry, I should have mentioned that there can be another object having **entityTitle** as "Opportunities". My aim was to group every object having entityTitle as "Opportunities" into one object.

Comment: @Shilly Thank you for such quick response! I did not understand the answer, but seriously Thanks man.

Comment: We have several methods on arrays. `.map()` will replace everything in an array with something else on a 1-to-1 basis. So if your array is 10 long, the mapping will be 10 long. `.reduce()` will transform an array into anything else, so we can use it to transform an array of length 10 into in this case, a shorter array. And that's perfect, since we want to group by entityTitle, and then merge the metdata of all the entityObjects of each title into an array.

Comment: So first we reduce the array into an object. We set the objects properties to our entityTitles and have them be the new object with a searchResults property as an array. So after the reduction we have: `{ "Opportunities" : { "entityTitle": Opportunities", "searchResults": [ ... ] }, "Reports": {...}}`. But we're onyl interested in the values of that object, not the keys. SO we use Object.values to extract those from the object into a new array.